# HTTP 400 of "AAAy H.mp3" but not "AAAy L.mp3"

Tags: http, curl

Ok, this is weird, and I can fix it by getting rid of spaces, but what is going on?

I have two files on my website, `AAAy H.mp3` and `AAAy L.mp3`. I can browse to them just fine.

When I do:

```
curl "http://mikehelland.com/omg/AAAy L.mp3"
```

I get the mp3 file.

When I do:

```
curl "http://mikehelland.com/omg/AAAy H.mp3"
```

I get `400`, bad request. Also doing:

```
curl "http://mikehelland.com/omg/AAAY H.mp3"
```

yields a `400`.

Change the `H` to an `L` or `A` or `M` or anything else seems to work fine. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of how server interprets space in file name, try to replace it with %20 (which represents space symbol in url) like this:

curl "http://mikehelland.com/omg/AAAy%20H.mp3"

If you try to acess your file with browser and will open developer console, you will found that browser inserts this %20 in GET request. So it is the reason why you can access file with browser, but not from terminal.

Also, try to add --verbose option to curl command. I noticed that when you access some inexistent file without space in name, the is the field in response 'Server: Apache/2', but when you add space it is 'Server: nginx'.

So maybe there is special case when server stops handling requset because it can't distinguish what to do with first line in request

```
GET /omg/AAAy H.mp3 HTTP/1.1
```

because it expects **HTTP/1.1** after **/omg/AAAy**, but not weird **H.mp3**. And maybe server looks at first symbol in "H.mp3" when parse for HTTP, and it made things broken. So I think the reason why "/omg/AAAy H.mp3" doesn't work, but "/omg/AAAy L.mp3" works is due to parsing mechanism of the server. Of course, without %20 all variants are forbidden by standard.

Comment: I realize that, and I mentioned I could solve the problem that way. But why does "AAAy A.mp3" work and not "AAAy H.mp3". That's what I'm curious about.

Comment: Makes sense that H is special then.